# Concatenate PCA components with rest of features in dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am looking for a way to apply a Sparse PCA to my dataset while still keeping the original features intact, so that I could try a classifier algorithm.

The way to insert PCA into a pipeline is quite simple:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import SparsePCA
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier



scaler = StandardScaler()
pca    = SparsePCA(n_components=2)
rf     = RandomForestClassifier()

pipeline_1 = Pipeline(steps=[
('scaler', scaler),
('PCA', pca),
('classifier', rf)
])
```

However, this will reduce the dimensionality of the original dataset. What I need is some way to concatenate the components found by the Sparce PCA into the original dataset.

I have seen that using *passthrough* or *FeatureUnion* or *compose.make_column_transformer* could work, but I still can't figure out how to apply it. Any suggestions?

DF example:

Before pipeline:

```
   feature1  feature2 ...
0     1         2
1     2         4
2     3         6
3     4         8
4     5         10
5     6         12
```

After pipeline:

```
   feature1  feature2 ... PCA_comp_1  PCA_comp_1 
0     1         2     ...   result1     result1
1     2         4     ...   result2     result2
2     3         6     ...   result3     result3
3     4         8     ...     ...         ...
4     5         10    ...     ...         ...
5     6         12    ...     ...         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I get it correct, so you just use the first two parts:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import SparsePCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

scaler = StandardScaler()
pca    = SparsePCA(n_components=2)

pipeline_1 = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler),('PCA', pca)])
```

An example dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = load_breast_cancer()
X = pd.DataFrame(data.data,columns=data.feature_names)
y = data.target
```

Get the PC scores in a dataframe and then concat:

```
PC = pd.DataFrame(pipeline_1.fit(X).transform(X),columns=['PC1','PC2'])
pd.concat([X,PC],axis=1)
```